# ERROR in node_modules/karma/config.tpl.ts:13:18 - error TS1109: Expression expected. Updated Angular 9

Tags: angular, typescript, jasmine, karma-runner

I am facing below error, i have updated angular 9, so didn't degrade typescript version. can anybody please help, i tried lot of things.

node_modules/karma/config.tpl.ts:66:16 - error TS1005: ',' expected.

node_modules/karma/config.tpl.ts:67:3 - error TS1005: ',' expected.

Package.json

```
"devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.900.6",
    "@angular-devkit/core": "^9.0.6",
    "@angular/cli": "^9.0.6",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~9.0.6",
    "@angular/language-service": "~9.0.6",
    "@types/jasmine": "2.8.6",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "^13.9.1",
    "codelyzer": "^5.1.2",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.99.1",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~4.0.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-cli": "~1.0.1",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-html-reporter": "^0.2.7",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.2",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "karma-junit-reporter": "^1.2.0",
    "karma-typescript": "^5.0.0",
    "node-sass": "^4.11.0",
    "protractor": "~5.4.0",
    "ts-node": "~8.6.2",
    "tslint": "~6.1.0",
    "typescript": "^3.8.3"
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try deleting `node_modules` and making the following changes:

```
"@types/jasmine": "^3.0.0",
"@types/jasminewd2": "^2.0.0",
....
"jasmine-core": "^3.0.0",
"karma": "^4.0.0",
"karma-chrome-launcher": "^3.0.0",
"karma-cli": "^2.0.0",
...// update the rest as well.
```

Uninstall the version of `node.js` you have and re-install the latest stable version. Then run `npm install`. See if that works.

Comment: hi @AliF50 , its  not working, i have stable version of node v12.16.1 and deleted nodemodule folder and than did npm install, please suggest another approach, if i downgraded the typescript than its working fine but getting below error. ERROR in The Angular Compiler requires TypeScript >=3.6.4 and <3.8.0 but 3.6.2 was found instead.

Comment: I am not sure then. Create a new Angular 9 project, see its package.json and copy it as much as possible and then add your dependencies using the latest versions and then do an npm install.